# Find the EigenValues and EigenVectors of the matrix associated with quadratic form

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

Problem: Find the EigenValues and EigenVectors of the matrix associated with quadratic forms $2x^2+6y^2+2z^2+8xz$.

I know how to convert a set of polynomial equations to a matrix but I have no clue how to convert this single quadratic equation with 3 variables into a matrix. Google tells me to use Cayley-Hamilton theorem... how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a start. You want a symmetric matrix. The diagonal elements correspond to the squares, and the non-diagonals to half the mixed monomials:
$$
2x^2+6y^2+2z^2+8xz=
\left(
\matrix{
 x \cr
 y \cr
 z \cr
}
\right)^T
\left(
\matrix{
 2 & 0 & 4 \cr
 0 & 6 & 0 \cr
 4 & 0 & 2 \cr
}
\right)
\left(
\matrix{
 x \cr
 y \cr
 z \cr
}
\right)
$$
With $A$ the square matrix above, the characteristic polynomial is then
$$
\eqalign{
p(\lambda)
&=
\det\left(A-\lambda I\right)=
\left(
\matrix{
 \lambda-2 & 0 & -4 \cr
 0 & \lambda-6 & 0 \cr
 -4 & 0 & \lambda-2 \cr
}
\right)
\cr
&=
(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-6)+16(\lambda-6)
\cr
&=
(\lambda+2)(\lambda-6)^2
}
$$
so there should be one eigenvector for $\lambda=-2$
and two for $\lambda=6$.

As to your question in the comments about where to read more...the simple answer is that you would want to look at the [equation of a conic](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/simple.html#conic-mat), and the matrix form allows you to identify the axes of symmetry.

There is a beautiful result called [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) concerning the solutions of the homogeneous equation $\mathbb{x}^TA\mathbb{x}=1$ for [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) (i.e. real [hermitian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix)) matrices $A$, which is a quadratic form and can be [extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Geometric_Meaning) to nonhomogeneous equations $\mathbb{x}^TA\mathbb{x}+\mathbb{b}^T\mathbb{x}=1$ (not discussed here). By homogeneous, we mean that all LHS monomials have the same degree $n$, and where the $1$ on the RHS could be replaced by any positive constant $r^n$ to scale the "unit" solution by the factor $r$ to an arbitrary [level set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) of the same shape (multiplying by $-1$ changes the geometry to the opposite signature, explained below). Sylvester's law states that the homogeneous equation describes either an [ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid), or a [hyperboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) of $k$ sheets, depending on the number $k$ of negative eigenvalues of $A$, which is an [invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28mathematics%29) under [similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similar_matrix) or [change of basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_a_linear_transformation) transformations. (If $A\mathbb{x}=\lambda\mathbb{x}$ and $B=TAT^{-1}$ for $T$ invertible then $\mathbb{y}=B\mathbb{x}$ satisfies [$B\mathbb{y}=\lambda\mathbb{y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110629/similar-matrices-have-same-eigenvalue-stuck#comment258358_110629).)

I have oversimplified because actually the geometry of the solution depends on the [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28quadratic_form%29#Real_quadratic_forms) of $A$, an invariant including $k$ but also including the number of zero eigenvalues, counting multiplicity or viewed as the multiset of eigenvalues, called the spectrum of $A$. The signature $\sigma$ of $A$ is thus characterized by the triple $(n_+,n_0,n_-)$ representing the number of positive, zero, and negative eigenvalues, and the number of possible signatures depends on how many [ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_partition_of_a_set) [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) there are of $n$ into three *nonnegative* summands, which is ${n+2}\choose{2}$ by a simple argument, e.g. [Example 5 on page 7 here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LaurendiPartitions.pdf). The opposite signature mentioned above is then just the reversed tuple.

This can be geometrically visualized using the [eigendecomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues#Eigendecomposition) of $A$. Let $T$ be a matrix whose $i^\text{th}$ column contains a unit eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, ordered in nonincreasing sequence $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\dots\lambda_n$. (We further require the eigenvectors to span the complete eigensubspaces in case there are repeated eigenvalues, which is guaranteed by the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) or [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_form) for $A$ [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_decomposition#Normal_matrices) or [*diagonalizable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable).) Then $T^{-1}$ transforms the solution set onto the solution set of the equation $\sum_{i=0}^{n_+}x_i^2-\sum_{i=n-n_-}^{n}x_i^2=1$, corresponding to the "normalized" equation $\mathbb{x}^TI_\sigma\mathbb{x}=1$, where $I_\sigma$ is the diagonal matrix with the first $n_+$ diagonal entries $+1$, the middle $n_0$ entries $0$, and the last $n_-$ diagonal entries $-1$. These describe various hypersurfaces of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or of lower dimension in degenerate cases when $n_0>0$, i.e. when $A$ is singular. The eigenvectors in the columns of $T$ thus point to the axes of symmetry for these ellipsoids and hyperboloids.
[Witt's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem)(s), [isometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) and [isotropies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_subspace) are also helpful to understand quadratic forms over an arbitrary field.

Sylvestor's law is related to the more general [spectral decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices) of a hermitian matrix $A$, which is a special case of both the [Schur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) and [singular value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) decompositions, and of [Sylvester's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula), since the orthogonal projections $P_{\lambda_i}$ onto the eigenspaces of each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ mentioned in the spectral decomposition formula are actually the Frobenius covariants $A_i$ of $A$. There are many other types of [matrix decompositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) as well. The quadratic form $\mathbb{x}^TA\mathbb{x}$ above can also be viewed as a [symmetric bilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_bilinear_form) $\mathbb{x}^TA\mathbb{y}$ with $\mathbb{y}=\mathbb{x}$. For visualization, it's also nice to look at [ruled surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface).

Comment: Thanks! >The diagonal elements correspond to the squares <-- which theorem/property says that and where can I read more?

Comment: First, try multiplying out $\left(\matrix{x\cr y}\right)^T\left(\matrix{a&b\cr b&a}\right)\left(\matrix{x\cr y}\right)$ by hand to convince yourself. If not convinced, repeat with a $3\times3$. There's lots of good material searching for "quadratic form matrix".

Answer (score 0):

In terms of just simply converting the quadratic expression into a matrix. 
You can just do it as follows...
If you want to form a symmetric matrix consider the following 3x3 matrix:

```
                 X  A  B
                 A  Y  C  
                 B  C  Z
```

- 1.The position of the X, Y and Z represent the coefficients of X, Y and
  Z  SQUARED, respectively.

  - In your case these are
  - X=2
  - Y=6
  - Z=2
- 2. The As represent the equal partition of the xy coefficient.
- in your case the coefficient of xy =0
- equally portioning that: 0/2=0
- so A=0
- 3. The Bs represent the equal partition of the xz coefficient
- in your case the coefficient of xz = 8
- equally partitioning that: 8/2 =4
- so B=4
- 4. C represents the equal partition of the yz coefficient
- in your case the coefficient for yz =0
- equally partitioning that: 0/2 = 0
- so C =0

So the final matrix you obtain, plugging in all those coefficients:

```
2  0  4
0  6  0
4  0  2
```

Then of course remember to x(transpose) and x vector to actually turn in into an equation.