# Is there a name for a matrix where the column space equals the row space? Does it have any interesting properties?

Tags: linear-algebra

I sat down to write a linear algebra take-home exam problem where I would give a $4\times4$ matrix $A$ and ask for bases for these six spaces: $\mathrm{Col}\,A$, $\mathrm{Row}\,A$, $\mathrm{Nul}\,A$, $\mathrm{Col}\,A^t$, $\mathrm{Row}\,A^t$, $\mathrm{Nul}\,A^t$. Trivially, a basis for $\mathrm{Col}\,A$ will work for $\mathrm{Row}\,A^t$, and likewise with $\mathrm{Row}\,A$ and $\mathrm{Col}\,A^t$; that was meant to be part of the test.

I expected $\mathrm{Nul}\,A$ and $\mathrm{Nul}\,A^t$ to be different. I worked on the first $4\times4$ matrix that came to mind: $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\5&6&7&8\\9&10&11&12\\13&14&15&16\end{bmatrix}$. To my surprise, the standard method for finding the basis of the null space led me to see that in this case, $\mathrm{Nul}\,A=\mathrm{Nul}\,A^t$. (And since I do not want students to think this will always be the case, I have to try a different matrix.)

As a consequence of the orthogonality of row and null spaces, $\mathrm{Row}\,A=\mathrm{Row}\,A^t$. So we have a matrix where: $$\mathrm{Col}\,A^t=\mathrm{Row}\,A=\mathrm{Row}\,A^t=\mathrm{Col}\,A$$ $$\mathrm{Nul}\; A=\mathrm{Nul}\;A^t$$ all of which is equivalent to just knowing $$\mathrm{Row}\, A=\mathrm{Col}\,A$$
or to just knowing $$\mathrm{Nul}\, A=\mathrm{Nul}\,A^t$$And these are equivalent to the existence of a matrix $B$ such that $AB=A^t$, since the rows of $A$ (columns of $A^t$) are linear combinations of the columns of $A$.

Now any invertible matrix would automatically have these properties, since the null space of an invertible matrix is $\{\vec0\}$. And any symmetric matrix will automatically have these properties, since $A=A^t$. But it seems like a noninvertible, asymmetric square matrix will rarely have these properties. (In the $2\times 2$ case, there are none.)

With general $n\times n$ matrices again, I would like to know

1. Is there a name for this kind of matrix ($\mathrm{Row}\,A=\mathrm{Row}\,A^t$)? Perhaps additionally demanding noninvertible asymmetric specimens?
2. Does this kind of matrix have any interesting applications?
3. If we fix $\mathrm{rank}\, A$, do matrices of this form make an interesting surface in $M_{n\times n}$?
4. If so, what is the dimension of this surface?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to view this question in light of the singular value decomposition, $A=U \Sigma V^T$, where $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Then when the matrix has rank $k$ the question is whether the first $k$ columns of $U$ span the same space as the first $k$ columns of $V$ (rows of $V^T$).

Comment: To show that the set of these matrices is a manifold, I guess the standard approach would be to find a smooth map from the space of all n-by-n matrices to some other vector space, which is zero for precisely the matrices you are interested in, then apply the Regular Value Theorem.

Answer (score 8):

A geometric characterization of these matrices would be the following:

An $(n\times n)$-matrix $A$ is the same as a linear transformation $A:\ {\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$. Provide ${\mathbb R}^n$ with the standard scalar product.

*Claim:* The condition ${\rm Col}\,A={\rm Row}\,A$ is equivalent to ${\rm ker}\,A=({\rm im}\, A)^\perp$. In particular any orthogonal projection would have this property.

*Proof.* The condition ${\rm Col}\,A={\rm Row}\,A$ means that ${\rm im}\,A={\rm im}\,A^t$. Take an $x\in{\ker}\,A$. Then
$$0=\langle A x,y\rangle=\langle x,A^t y\rangle\qquad\forall y\ ;$$
therefore $x$ is orthogonal to ${\rm im}\,A^t={\rm im}\,A$. It follows that ${\rm ker}\,A\subset({\rm im}\,A)^\perp$, whence ${\rm ker}\,A=({\rm im}\, A)^\perp$ by counting dimensions.

Conversely, assume that ${\rm ker}\,A=({\rm im}\, A)^\perp$. Take an $x\in{\rm im}\,A^t$. Then $x=Az$ for a $z\in{\mathbb R}^n$, and we have
$$\langle u,x\rangle=\langle u,A^t z\rangle=\langle Au,z\rangle =0\qquad\forall u\in{\rm ker}\,A\ .$$
It follows that ${\rm im}\,A^t\subset({\rm ker}\,A)^\perp={\rm im}\,A$ and therefore ${\rm im}\,A^t={\rm im}\,A$, as $A$ and $A^t$ have the same rank.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps these should be called
***scaled $r$-dimensional cosets
of the unitary group*** $U(n)$.

By theorem 14 on page 6 of Travis Schedler's [lecture 18](http://www-math.mit.edu/~trasched/18.700.f10/lect17-article.pdf),
every $A$, when viewed as a linear transformation,
has a polar decomposition $A=S\sqrt{A^*A}$,
where $S$ is an isometry (unitary over $\mathbb{C}$
or orthogonal over $\mathbb{R}$),
$A^*A$ is positive-definite (for $A\ne0$) by a previous theorem,
and its square root is defined as the
unitary/orthogonal conjugate $U\Lambda'U^*$
of the diagonal matrix $\Lambda'=\sqrt{\Lambda}$
of nonnegative square roots of its eigenvalues $(\Lambda_{ii}=\lambda_i)$
from its (necessarily diagonal) Schur decomposition $A^*A=U\Lambda U^*$.
Similarly, $A^*=S\,'\sqrt{A^*A}$ for another isometry $S\,'$,
since $(A^*A)^*=A^*A$. Thus $A^T=S\,'S^*A$,
so I think your $B$ would have to also be an isometry,
and over $\mathbb{R}$, special orthogonal (with determinant $1$).
If we place the $\lambda_i$ in nonincreasing order
(by permuting the columns of $U$),
we can easily see that $\Lambda'$ lives in an embedding (injection)
of $r$-dimensional diagonal matrices
with strictly positive eigenvalues (scale matrices)
from $\mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$
into $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Thus, $A=S\,U\Lambda'\,U^*$ is an isometry ($S$) or "permuted rotation"
of an $r$-dimensional inhomogeneous dilation ($\Lambda'$)
about the axes of some orthonomal basis ($U$) of $\mathbb{R}^n$,
giving us a pretty good geometric picture of the matrix space
$\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\mid A\mathbb{R}^n=A^T\mathbb{R}^n\}$.

Note, also, that unitary matrices (isometries) are of the
form $U=e^{iH}$ for $H$ self-adjoint commuting with $U$.
In fact, we can define a $C^\infty$ ([exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map))
map $U:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
by $U(t)=e^{itH}$ with derivatives $U^{(n)}(t)=t\,U^*H^n$.
The space (a [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)) of self-adjoint matrices $H$
(or anti-self-adjoint if we drop the $i$ above),
therefore, gives us the tangent space at each point
of the space $U(n)$ of unitary matrices, which is a [Lie Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group).

I have not found a better *necessary* condition than
Chrisitan's, ${\rm ker}\,A=({\rm im}\, A)^\perp$,
or those given in the OP, e.g., $\exists B:A^TB=A$,
for $A\mathbb{F}^n=A^T\mathbb{F}^n$ to hold,
i.e. for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$
to share the same image or column space as its transpose
$A^T$ (or conjugate transpose $A^*$).
The best way to characterize these matrices is therefore
probably with a list of equivalent conditions.

A *sufficient* condition is that the matrix
$A\in\mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$
(e.g. $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R} \text{ or }\mathbb{C}$)
is [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable), meaning ([TFAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterisation)):

- $\exists\,G:A=G\Lambda G^{-1}$
  with $G$ invertible and 
  $\Lambda$ diagonal in
  $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$
  ([spectral/eigen- decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Eigendecomposition))
- the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue equals
  its algebraic multiplicity
- the sum of the dimensions of its eigenspaces is equal to $n$
- there exists a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$
- the number of linearly independent eigenvectors for each eigenvalue 
  $\lambda$ equals the algebraic degree of $(x-\lambda)$ as a factor
  of the characteristic polynomial of $A$
- its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors
  (splits and is squarefree) over $\mathbb{F}$
- ($\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$):
  each [Jordan block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) in the [***real***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices)
  [Jordan decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Jordan_decomposition) of $A$
  contains no $2\times2$ identity
  matrix superdiagonal blocks
- $\exists\,U,T:A=UTU^{-1}$ has a
  "complete"/complex [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Schur_decomposition) over $F$
  with $U$ unitary and $T$ upper triangular,
  which is only true if all eigenvalues are in $F$
  (and always true for $F=\mathbb{C}$)
- ($\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$):
  the Schur decomposition over the reals $A=QSQ^{-1}$
  with $Q$ orthogonal and $S$ block upper triangular
  has only $1\times 1$ (and no $2\times 2$) diagonal blocks within $S$

A *stronger* sufficient condition (implying the above)
is that $A$ is a [normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix), meaning ([TFAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#Equivalent_definitions)):

- $AA^*=A^*A$ ($A$ commutes with its conjugate transpose $A^*$)
- $A$ is [*unitarily*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices) [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable)
  ($A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$ for $U^*=U^{-1}$)
- $\exists U:A^*=AU$.

which (linguistically at least) completes the analogy
with [normal subgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) in group theory,
for which left and right [cosets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset) are the same.

In these cases, the geometric characterization would be
that $A$ is an anisotropic scaling or [inhomogeneous dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhomogeneous_dilation)
(which necessarily includes projection when $\text{rank}\;A\lt n$)
after an orthogonal (or unitary for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$)
change of basis (with no isometry $S$).
In this way, it is analogous to a [self-adjoint operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Geometric_interpretation).

When $A$ is [positive definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), its
Schur, [spectral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_decomposition), and [singular value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)
decompositions all [coincide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Notes).
When $A$ is normal, its [polar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) factors commute:
$A=UP=PU$ (for $P$ positive *[semi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Positive-semidefinite)*-definite).
In general there exists a polar factorization
$A=UP$, but $U$ and $P$ are not guaranteed to commute.

The list of [equivalences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#Equivalent_definitions) of normal (and diagonalizable) matrices
is quite long, surely longer than in the wikipedia link,
so there are probably many applications.
One nice such application is in the
[classification of quadratic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110880/quadratic-equation-matrix/110885#110885).
For the dimensions of subspaces of rank $k$,
have a look at [Grassmanian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) and [Stieffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) manifolds.

An earlier version of this post had errors,
based on a misunderstanding of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices)
(in fact,  an  upper triangular, rather than
         block upper triangular, Schur form
only exists for normal matrices whose
characteristic or minimal polynomials have
*all* their roots in $\mathbb{F}$).

Comment: This cannot be right. It is not necessary that $AA^*=A^*A$. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\mathrm{Row}\,A=\mathrm{Col}\,A=\mathrm{Span}\{\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2\}$. So $A$ is the kind of matrix I am asking about. Just for the sake of generality, this matrix also has less than full rank. But $AA^*=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ while $A^*A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's not necessary at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let us study this question in a general setting of $n \times n$ matrices.
For a given $n \times n$ matrix $A$, we denote its nullspace by $\mathcal{N}(A)$, and its column space by $\mathcal{C}(A)$.

Recall that the orthogonal complement of a vector subspace $V$ is 
$$V^\perp := \{\vec{x} : \forall \vec{v} \in V.~(\vec{x}^T \vec{v} = 0) \}.$$
It is well known that for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$ it holds that $(\mathcal{N}(A))^\perp = \mathcal{R}(A)$, where $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is the row space of $A$.  In particular, $\mathcal{C}(A) = \mathcal{R}(A^T)$ implies that $(\mathcal{C}(A))^\perp = \mathcal{N}(A^T)$.

Now let $A$ be any $n \times n$ matrix with $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{C}(A)$. From our preceding discussion, it is thus necessary and sufficient that $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(A^T)$.  We shall first show that such an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ must be of the form
$$Q \left(\begin{array}{cc} X & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) Q^T,$$
where $X$ is an $r \times r$ matrix whose rank, $r$, is equal to that of $A$, and some bordering $0$'s may be absent if $A$ is of full rank $n$.

$Proof$.  Extend any given basis $\{e_{r+1},\ldots,e_n\}$ for $\mathcal{N}(A)$ to a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_r,e_{r+1},\ldots,e_n\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $P = (\vec{e}_i^T)$ and $Q = P^{-1}$.  Clearly, both $P$ (as well as $Q$) is invertible since its column vectors $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ are linearly independent.  Since $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(A^T)$, it follows that $PAP^T = \left(\begin{array}{cc} X & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),$ where $r(X) = r(PAP^T) = r(A) = r$.  Hence $A$ is of the desired form.
The proof is thus complete.

Now we establish that any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ of the above form has to satisfy the equation $$\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(A^T),$$ and hence the condition that $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{R}(A)$.

$Proof.$ Suppose $A = Q \left(\begin{array}{cc} X & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) Q^T$, where $X$ is an invertible matrix with $r(X) = r(A)$.  Writing the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc} X & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ as $Y$, we have that $\vec{x} \in \mathcal{N}(A)$ iff $QYQ^T \vec{x} = 0$ iff $YQ^T \vec{x} = 0$.  Now since $X$ is an invertible matrix of size $r$, the last condition is equivalent to $Y^TQ^T \vec{x} = 0$, which in turn is equivalent to $QY^TQ^T \vec{x} = 0$ iff $x \in \mathcal{N}(A^T)$.  This shows that $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(A^T)$.